# BigQuery Public dataset missing

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dataset

I am taking a coursera course and I am trying to access this dataset from BigQuery's public database:
bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips

I have used in in the past for another project but now the entire tables has cells with NULL.

Not sure if it has been deleted or there was an error somewhere. I am sure users do not have access to be able to delete the contents of this table, so there is no way I could have accidentally changed the cells to NULL permanently right?

If anyone can assist with this, it will be a huge help as I need this dataset to continue with my learning. [image: Screenshot of the dataset]

I have tried refreshing the page but it stays the same. Not sure what else I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `citibike_trips` table of the BQ public dataset `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike` does show null values and empty values for string datatype. However if you apply the count function on any column say `tripduration`, it shows a definite number which means that the values are not actually null/empty.

[image]

Looks like the table is under upgadation but, I would still suggest opening a public Issue [tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) thread with Google Cloud Platform so that BigQuery engineers can look into this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will go ahead and open the public issue tracker thread.

Answer (score -1):

This table is not empty, you'll find NULLs in the first fifty-something thousand rows. The table itself contains more than 50M rows.